# Analytic closed-form solution

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I have the following equation:
$$\left(\frac{x}{\cosh(x)}\right)^2-x\tanh(x)+\ln\cosh(x)=0$$
and I would like to know if there is some analytic closed form solution.

WA gives me two non-zero solutions $\pm 1.2837768\dots$ which seems intriguingly close to e.g. $ 5/8 \pi\frac{1}{\sinh^2(9877427/9504216)}$. I am wondering maybe there is some closed form solution.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I see no reason why there should be a closed-form solution. $9877427/9504216$ looks _extremely_ arbitrary. By the way, your number is also close to $12837768/10000000$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But still, the equation is equal to $xf^\prime(x)-f(x)=0$, where $f(x)=x\tanh(x)-\log\cosh(x)$ and after substitution it is almost a quadratic equation. So maybe there is some "trick" which could give a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation contains an elementary function. An elementary function is a function that is generated by applying only $\exp$, $\ln$ and/or algebraic functions (algebraic operations).

You are looking for an inverse of your elementary function that is also an elementary function.

If you convert the elementary standard functions in your equation to their representation with only $\exp$ and $\ln$, you will see that your function is an algebraic function of $x$, $e^x$ and $\ln(e^x+e^{-x})$. These expressions are algebraically independent if $x\neq 0$. Therefore your function possibly cannot have partial inverses that are elementary functions.

MAPLE, MATHEMATICA have no result in closed form except $x=0$.